# Getting a error when trying to delete a column from my database using Vue Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, vue.js, axios

I'm building a Node.js PostgresSQL Server from which I get my Data and then I want to show them in my Vue Client. Now I'm stuck at deleting columns from my client. When I try to delete it I get this error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QctHY.jpg

I already tried to just test my route by pasting the link http://localhost:3000/buch/del/9781201600312 and it worked it deleted the column from my database so I think the route is working but with my client is a problem

My Axios Call:

```
   async delSpalte(isbn){
        await axios({
            url:"http://localhost:3000/buch/del/" + isbn,
            method: "delete"
        });
    }
```

I put my Data in this table:

```
        <tr v-for="x in books">
        <th @click="CurrClickedTitle = x.titel; getAnzahlBuecher(x.isbn)"> 
        {{x.titel}}</th>
        <td>{{x.isbn}}</td>
        <td>{{x.erscheinungsdatum}}</td>
        <td>{{x.preis}}</td>
        <td><button @click="delSpalte(x.isbn); getBuecher();" class="btn btn-danger">Löschen</button></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> by pasting the link

Do you mean you paste the link into the browser? if yes then you're using the wrong HTTP method, change it to GET.

```
method: "get"
```